# BAD_ACCESS on very low number of users during getaddrinfo

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-management, getaddrinfo-a

Okay, I am completely at a loss here.
A small percentage of users seem to have BAD_ACCESS errors in my hostname translation.

The complete crash below:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: 0x000000000000000d, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  21

Thread 21 Crashed:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8406a446 _mdns_query_callback + 275
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff84057fc8 handle_query_response + 296
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff84057433 DNSServiceProcessResult + 717
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff84069cf3 _mdns_query_mDNSResponder + 1180
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff84069090 _mdns_search + 1458
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff840682f1 _mdns_addrinfo + 716
6   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff84067373 search_addrinfo + 146
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff84066d9c si_addrinfo + 1352
8   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff840667ad getaddrinfo + 159
9   com.NZBVortex.NZBVortex         0x000000010002a4d7 -[CFNetworkStream getHostAddress:sockAddressIn:] + 152
10  com.NZBVortex.NZBVortex         0x000000010002a622 -[CFNetworkStream openBSDSocket::] + 252
```

Here is the code I use to resolve the dns (important parts).
Am I missing something here; could I add more checks?
It's just an very low number of users, so thousands have no issues.

Part of my hostname resolve code:
My [CFNetworkStream openBSDSocket::] method

```
-(bool)openBSDSocket:(NSString*)hostName:(int)port {
    struct sockaddr_in remoteAddr;

    remoteAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    remoteAddr.sin_port = htons(port);

    if ([self getHostAddress:hostName sockAddressIn:&remoteAddr]) {
        //some non-related code
    }
}
```

Which in turn calls the [self getHostAddress:xxxx] method
Below the complete method:

```
-(bool)getHostAddress:(NSString*)hostname sockAddressIn:(struct sockaddr_in*)result {
    struct addrinfo hints, *res, *iterateRes;
    int retval;

    memset (&hints, 0, sizeof (struct addrinfo));
    hints.ai_family = PF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags |= AI_CANONNAME;

    int maxLength = [hostname length]+1;
    const char hostNameC[maxLength];
    struct in_addr *inAddr;
    bool foundAddress = NO;

    if (hostNameC!=NULL) {
        [hostname getCString:(void*)&hostNameC maxLength:maxLength encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

        retval = getaddrinfo (hostNameC, NULL, &hints, &res);
        if (retval == 0) {

            iterateRes = res;
            while (iterateRes && !foundAddress) {
                switch (iterateRes->ai_family)
                {
                    case AF_INET:
                        inAddr = &((struct sockaddr_in *) iterateRes->ai_addr)->sin_addr;
                        memcpy(&(result->sin_addr), inAddr, sizeof(inAddr));
                        foundAddress = YES;
                }
                iterateRes = iterateRes->ai_next;
            }
        }

        freeaddrinfo (res);
    }

    return foundAddress;
}
```

Could you give me a consult? I really seem to be stuck here, whey are those (low) number of users see issues in this code? Do I need additional checks?

I really could use your tips/consult.

IMPORTANT: the affected users say it only happens if the network gets dropped. But I can't accept that a dropping network connection could create the above problems?

Edit:
I did a leak test; a long time by faking no DNS result (if (retval != 0)), but no memory leaks on my Mac.

Comment: What OS versions? And is the crash stack always the same?

Comment: So far just one crash; but if there is one there will be more :) It's on a 10.6.4.

Comment: You named *your class* CFNetworkStream? Bad idea; if Apple ever adds such a class, the two will collide and your app may break. Use your own prefix that doesn't duplicate any of Apple's.

Comment: I know. Don't worry about it.

Comment: @GerTeunis I've encountered this crash too on one test machine (with identical trace within getaddrinfo). Just out of interest, were you running a binary that's forked but hasn't called exec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I have fixed it by making sure the getaddrinfo isn't called too often by too many threads at the same time. Also added a local cache for the results (a in app dns cache).

I think the real problem was that when users have connection problems the many connection threads might have over-flooded the getaddrinfo too much until it broke.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for one thing the test `if (hostNameC!=NULL)` is not accomplishing anything: `hostnameC` is an array (not a pointer), it will never be == NULL. So, are you handling the case where hostname==NULL, or hostname is zero-length?

You aren't checking the return value of `-getCString: maxLength: encoding:`; if that call fails, you will be passing uninitialized garbage to `getaddrinfo`.

Comment: HostNameC!=NULL you are right there, not a breaker though. I used a malloc before in one of my tests. that code can be removed. The users reported it works fine (so a good hostname, which is filled by a preference) for a long time and after a while it break. But I add more test code there! Thanks so far.